# Multiple domains pointing to different directories at Heroku

Tags: heroku

Due security reasons, we need multiple domains pointing to static files of our site *in different directories* for each domain.

However the entire directory structure (containing the above mentioned directories) should be controlled by one Python application.

Is it possible with Heroku? Or do we need our own VPS instead to implement this (multiple domains pointing to different directories with static files in one application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do this on Heroku. You'll need to have code that handles the request and looks at the requested domain and then has the correct files served.